# Raspberry pi how to use SpiDev open method

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spi

I'm trying to use SpiDev library on Rasbian, but I can't understand what open method arguments mean.

According to the document, [SpiDev.pdf](http://tightdev.net/SpiDev_Doc.pdf), it says,

> Syntax: open(bus, device)
>   Description: Connects the object to the specified SPI device.
>   open(X,Y) will open /dev/spidev-X.Y

What is bus and what is device?

I will use raspberry pi SPI funcion as below.

```
SCLK : PIN23  
MISO : PIN21  
MOSI : PIN19  
CE   : PIN24
```

So what kind of data should i set to open method arguments ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bus` will always be zero as there is only one on a Raspberry Pi.

The `dev` will be 0 or 1 depending on the **Chip Enable 0/1** pin.

Examples [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-pi-spi-and-i2c-tutorial/all).

Be sure to run `sudo raspi-config` and enable SPI and reboot before trying to use any SPI devices.